# Best way to do cross database union query in EF code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

i'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project with EF code first as database modelling. 
It's a multi user application in which everyone has it's own database, what i need now is the ability to list all Posts of all the user using the platform, so i search for cross database querying.
It seem EF doesn't support this type of query because the dbcontext is linked to a fixed connection string, then i ask you which method i can develop to achive my goal?

I was thinking on using two dbcontext, one for the database of the user and another database containing the data of all users, trying to duplicate CRUD operation both in personal and global database, but it seem very odd to do.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell more about your infrastructure. Is it one server, which has multiple databases, which all have different schemas?

Comment: @MareInfinitus i mean multiple database, maybe in different server as data or traffic began too high or for load balancing request(but in this case i have to find a way to have data duplicated istantanly on multiple database).

Answer (score 0):

if it is only " what i need now is the ability to list all Posts of all the user using the platform"

-> you can create sql server view use linked server query to get the data from different databases

Comment: but with a view i can only get but not update records, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure to return the data from the linked servers, then call this store procedure using ExecuteStoreQuery. Create an entity to hold the result set, and have EF hydrate the results.